How to implement ObjectBox with Android Version Catalog (TOML)
I couldn't implement ObjectBox plugin with:
objectbox = { id = "io.objectbox.objectbox-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "objectbox" }

The result error is: Was not found in any of the following sources.
My settings.gradle already has:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}


The ObjectBox Gradle plugin does not ship a Gradle plugin marker artifact. To work around this, add a plugin resolution rule that maps the dependency to a name of your choosing:
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "io.objectbox.plugin") {
                useModule("io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}

Then use that name in the TOML file:
objectbox = { id = "io.objectbox.plugin", version.ref = "objectbox" }

See also the related GitHub issue.

I have tried many ways then end up with buildscript block below plugins block in project build.gradle file.
buildscript {
    val objectBoxVersion = libs.versions.objectbox.get()
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectBoxVersion")
    }
}


Change it to:
objectbox = { id = "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "objectbox" }


':' is not allow in toml file. I have tried many ways then end up with buildscript block below plugins block in project build.gradle file.
